# Yii Console Application does not auto-import Model as web appliccation

Tags: yii, scheduled-tasks, console-application, cron-task

Here is my console.php which is same as main.php

```
return array(
'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
'name' => 'My Console Application',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload' => array('log'),

 // autoloading model and component classes
'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.extensions.*',
),
```

The web application has no problem access those functions. However, console application yields error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Myfunction::get_all_recipients()
```

An discussion of this problem is also found at

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/2344

Also tried suggestions

[Yii Command Line Does Not Autoload Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615888/yii-command-line-does-not-autoload-models)

but it still does not import model classes.

Comment: Why the second answer didn't help? Please show what model you want to import, where is located, and what's under `import` section of your console config now.

Comment: all the models are located under protected/models/* and the import section looks same like above no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution should work, but sometimes I use another approach. In the console command itself add the following:

```
Yii::import('application.models.YourModel');
```

or

```
Yii::import('application.models.Subfolder.YourModel');
```

if it's located in subfolder for example;

This should placed before your code is processed. This autoloads only models or classes that your need for current command.

Comment: This actually an ideal solution to the problem /thanks